# Ubuntu Touch .... how do you change the wallpaper?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Ubuntu Touch .... how do you change the wallpaper ?

Answer (score 0):

System Settings --> Background (In the personal category)

By default only one image is installed, so you will have to click on custom --> add image